# Execute a comand for each file within a directory

Tags: find, zsh, exec, basename

I need to convert a series of images from one format to another, but only the images within `$PWD`, ignoring anything in subdirectories. But I need to remove the original extension or suffix, in order to pass it to another software down the pipeline. I'm trying to use the following command

```
find . -type f -iname "*.pdf" -exec convert {} $(basename {} .pdf).png \;
```

The intention is to keep the `*.pdf` files, and have new `*.png` files. However, the resulting files instead end up with the extension `.pdf.png`

From what I understand, the `$(basename {} .pdf)` is being executed before the `find` command, resulting in a literal `{}`, and that's why the output of convert is `{}.png`.

Should I add any particular combination of `` "`´' ``, or maybe an explicit call to `sh -c`
to make this work?

I'm using zsh as my shell

Any help is appreciated

Edit: As pointed in the comments, the code and my accepted answer will process files in any possible subdirectories. To avoid this (whis is my original intention, although I don't have any subdirs)

`find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.pdf" -exec zsh -c 'convert $1 ${1:r}.png' _ {} \;`

Comment: Your question is unclear: The title says "each file in a directory", but your code snippet processes "each file in a directory or its subdirectories". Edit the question to make it clear what you want to do.

Comment: Actually, you did nothing to clarify what I mentioned, except that you now restrict your self to those entries in the direcrory tree, which are files....

Comment: Ok, I'll put the restriction for files only also within the text

Comment: What for? The point is not that you distinguish between files and directories - if you happen to have a directory foo.pdf, `convert` would likely just produce an error message -, but that the title of the question talks about files inside a directory, while your command processes files inside a directory **and in subdirectories** of this directory. A good solution for your question requires to know, what you want to achieve.

Comment: One more point which is unclear: In your attempt to solve the problem using `find`, you are searching for files ending in i.e. `.PDF` or `.Pdf` as well (since you are using `-iname`), but when you apply `basename`, you silently assume the extension `.pdf`.

Comment: I understand the point about the extension. The one about files in directories and subdirectories, seems more about contradiction in semantics and code. I added a ``-type f`` constraint in the find. I don't want to process any possible subdirectories, at least not right now. Thanks for the feedback. Should I change the title of my post as well?

Comment: `-type f` does not influence subdirectory search. `-depth` would do. I think you should clarify this - in particular, since the answer you accepted, **does** process subdirectories. I wonder why you accepted it then, if it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't realize it would be an issue, as I don't have any subdirectories

Comment: Well, it would be an issue if you - by accident - run the command inside your $HOME instead of the directory where your PDFs are stored. Its always advisable to ask a precise question. When you start to program, you also have initially a precise problem specification, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find`:

```bash
find . -type f -iname "*.pdf" -exec zsh -c 'convert $1 ${1:r}.png' _ {} \;
```

In just the current directory, not any subdirectories:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.pdf" -exec zsh -c 'convert $1 ${1:r}.png' _ {} \;
```

Using a shell loop. Unlike `find`, this does not launch a subshell for each file:

```bash
setopt extendedglob
for fl in (#i)**/*.pdf; do
    convert $fl ${fl:r}.png
done
```

In only the current directory:

```bash
...
for fl in (#i)*.pdf; do
...
```

Using a loop in an anonymous function so if fits comfortably in a single line
(directory and subdirectories / current directory only):

```bash
(){for a; convert $a $a:r.png} **/*.(pdf|PDF)
```

```bash
(){for a; convert $a $a:r.png} *.(pdf|PDF)
```

Using [`zmv`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv)
(recursive directory and subdirectories / current directory only):

```bash
autoload zmv # can be in ~/.zshrc
zmv -p convert '(#i)(*/)#*.pdf' '${f:r}.png'
```

```bash
zmv -p convert '(#i)*.pdf' '${f:r}.png'
```

The `r` (root) expansion modifier is described in the [history expansion section](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) of the `zsh` manual. Like `basename`, it removes the extension from a filename.

Comment: Thanks @gairfowl. I was looking for a syntax similar to the first one. I prefer the second one for scripts, but not for typing in the console. I will probably use both. Very useful insight and help. Thanks again!

Comment: For your `zmv` alternative, don't you need _extendedglob_ as well in order that `(#i)` works, or is `zmv` always using extended globbing?

Comment: @user1934428 - `zmv` always uses extendedglob. BUT: while testing the `zmv` part of the answer, I found that it does not handle the `**/` recursive directory glob operator correctly, and there may be a bug in `zsh`'s processing of the '=' test condition with extended globbing. An equivalent operator `(*/)#` does appear to work.